# How to write on polygons that are in turn drawn in svg element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, polygon

I have a "map" that is a set of polygons drawn by JavaScript on svg element. Is there any way to draw text inside (on top of) polygon that is drawn inside of svg element?

Should I try to draw text on the svg element on the same coordinates were polygon is drawn?

Thank you!

P.S. either clean JavaScript or jquery both will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The way of doing that is to simply add a <text> element using its x and y attributes to position it where you want on a given polygon (using whichever same JS way that you're using to add polygons, just creating a text element instead of a polygon element).

Be sure to put the text element after the polygon in the tree so that it paints on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Second option is to draw polygons and texts:
a) at 0,0 for top left corner
b) -x,-y for center

And then translate each polygon/text where you want them to be.

Comment: Essentially that is the same as drawing on required position. Thanks